# Java Paint Program

Tags: java, swing, paint, graphics2d

I have started a Java Paint program that seems to be working fine... There is just one problem. In my program I have it set up so that it repaint()'s ovals using MouseListener methods and overrides paintComponent(Graphics g). The problem is when I move my mouse to fast it begins to separate my ovals instead of making one smooth line when the mouse is dragged. Is there a way to fix this.

P.S. Keep in mind that I much rather use the fillOval method not the drawLine, because I still would like to set the stroke.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want better help, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still set a stroke to use to draw a line between two points. You should store the previous mouse position and interpolate between the last position and the current position to create a Line2D shape. Then create a stroke that has the desired width of your oval, and apply that stroke to Graphics context, then draw the line. [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html) has more information about strokes and shapes.

If you really want to continue drawing ovals, you could interpolate along the line between the start/end points and draw multiple ovals in a loop.

Comment: A lifesaver thanks!!! For future reference everyone I recommend checking this out if your designing a paint program. http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58137-java-mini-paint-program/

Answer (score 2):

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do painting. The example draws a Rectangle without problems as the mouse moves.